# Apex CPU time limit exceeded while creating a csv file

Tags: apex

I am getting Apex CPU time limit exceeded while running this code how to optimize this code, I have to create a csv file with all record of Account object

```
    List<Account > acclist = [Select id,name , CreatedDate , lastModifiedDate from Account limit 30000];
    string header = 'id, Name , CreatedDate, lastModifiedDate \n';
    string finalstr = header ;
    for(Account a: acclist)
    {
           string recordString = a.id+','+a.Name+','+a.CreatedDate+','+a.LastModifiedDate +'\n';
           finalstr +=  recordString;

    }
   System.debug('finalstr>>>>>'+finalstr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex CPU time limit exceeded may happen if you try to process too many records at a time.

If you have too many records you should consider using batch job passing 200 records at a time to your method.